# Java 2D array encirclement

Tags: java, arrays

I am tasked to make a program which returns true if in a 2D array 1-s encircle 0-s.

I tried something like this, but i cant find the right solution.

```
    public boolean checkGameState(){
    for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fields.length;j++){
            if(fields[i][j]!=0){
                if(row(i,j){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}

private boolean row(int a, int b){
    int checkI=a;
    int checkJ=b;
    while(fields[checkI][checkJ]==1){
        checkJ++;
    }
    while(fields[checkI][checkJ]==1){
        checkI++;
    }
    while(fields[checkI][checkJ]==1){
        checkJ--;
    }
    while(fields[checkI][checkJ]==1){
        checkI--;
    }
    return a==checkI && b==checkJ;
}
```

The 2D array looks something like this:

```
111100
100100
100101
111100
001100
```

For this array the method should return true.

Comment: "if in a 2D array 1-s encircle 0-s." what do you mean? Do you mean it should have atleast 1 zero's surrounded by?

Comment: So... you want to check if there is subset of `0`s in 2D array, which doesn't touch the bounds?

Comment: no need to check the first row and last "row", or the first and last "columns" in the array

Comment: Need to keep a reference to the previous row and next row also

Comment: no, dont has to be a surrounded 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm to eliminate all the zeros that are *not* encircled by ones, and then checking whether there are any left.

First, put all the zeros directly on the "fringe" of the 2D array into a queue. Then, use the flood fill algorithm to turn all of those into a different number (e.g., 2), and add the nodes next to them to the fringe set (either diagonally or only direct neighbours). Repeat until there are no more nodes in the fringe. Finally, check whether there are any more zeros in the array. If so, those were not connected to the fringe region and thus had to be "encircled" by ones.

```
// test data set up
int[][] data = {{1,1,1,1,0,0},
                {1,0,0,1,0,0},
                {1,0,0,1,0,1},
                {1,1,1,1,0,0},
                {0,0,1,1,0,0}};
int N = data.length, M = data[0].length;

// create queue of zeros on the "fringe"
Queue<int[]> fringe = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (data[i][0  ] == 0) fringe.add(new int[]{i,0  });
    if (data[i][M-1] == 0) fringe.add(new int[]{i,M-1});
}
for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    if (data[0  ][j] == 0) fringe.add(new int[]{0  ,j});
    if (data[N-1][j] == 0) fringe.add(new int[]{N-1,j});
}   

// do flood fill until no more zeros reachable
while (! fringe.isEmpty()) {
    int[] next = fringe.poll();
    int i = next[0], j = next[1];
    data[i][j] = 2;
    for (int di = -1; di <= 1; di++) {
        for (int dj = -1; dj <= 1; dj++) {
            try {
                if (data[i+di][j+dj] == 0) fringe.add(new int[]{i+di, j+dj});
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
        }   
    }
}

// check for remaining zeros
boolean encircled = false;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        System.out.print(data[i][j]);
        encircled |= data[i][j] == 0;
    }   
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println(encircled);
```

Example output:

```
111122
100122
100121
111122
221122
true
```

The complexity should be on the order of *O(NxM)*, since each of the *NxM* nodes can only appear once in the queue (plus a bit of overhead for constructing the queue and finding remaining zeros).

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that I have assumed that you need rectangle shape surrounding*

You need to find sequences for 3 or more `1` in one row.

```
xx1111xx // x means any number
```

For each sequence check if there is sequence of the same length 2 or more rows lower.

```
xx1111xx
xxxxxxxx
xx1111xx
```

For each "pair" of sequences check if they are connected with `1` on the edges.

```
xx1111xx
xx1xx1xx
xx1111xx
```

Comment: What if there's a "dent" in the border of ones?